# TypeScript: Method won't accept narrower type as argument

Tags: typescript

I have a `ValueLike<T>` type that's just a wrapper around value access (the value is either accessed directly or via a lazy-indexed view into an array). I also have a `ScalarLike<T>` type, which is there to signify `ValueLike<T>` + methods for a specific `T`. For example, `Num` class implements `ScalarLike<number>` and has methods like addition, division, etc... Finally, I have a `VariableLike<T>` (= array) type, from which I can access and into which I can push corresponding `ScalarLike`.

By my reasoning, `Num` is a narrower type than `ScalarLike<number>`, so it should be assignable as the argument to the push method for `VariableLike<number>`. However, when I try to do this, I get the following error:

```
type ValueLike<T> = {
  value: () => T;
};

class Value<T> implements ValueLike<T> {
  constructor(private val: T) {}
  value = () => this.val;
}

class View<T> implements ValueLike<T> {
  constructor(private array: T[], private index: () => number) {}
  value = () => this.array[this.index()];
}

type ScalarLike<T> = {
  value: () => T;
};

class Num implements ScalarLike<number> {
  constructor(private valueLike: ValueLike<number>) {}
  value = () => this.valueLike.value();
  add = (other: Num) => new Num(new Value(this.value() + other.value()));
  divideBy = (other: Num) => new Num(new Value(this.value() / other.value()));
  // ... other methods
}

type VariableLike<T> = {
  ith: (index: () => number) => ScalarLike<T>;
  push: (scalar: ScalarLike<T>) => number;
};

class NumVariable implements VariableLike<number> {
  constructor(private array: number[]) {}
  ith = (index: () => number) => new Num(new View(this.array, index));
  push = (num: Num) => {   // Error: Type 'ScalarLike<number>' is missing the following properties from type 'Num': valueLike, add, divideBy
    return this.array.push(num.value());
  };
}
```

(sorry for the long codeblock, but I thought that otherwise it might not be clear what I'm trying to do)

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, `Num` is narrower than `ScalarLike<number>`. But you're using the type in a parameter position here, so it needs to be wider! `VariableLike<number>` declares that the `push` implementation must accept **any** `ScalarLike<number>`. That contract is not fulfilled by only accepting `Num`s.

Comment: Btw, [avoid declaring only class fields with arrow function values - use method definitions instead](https://www.charpeni.com/blog/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think)!

Comment: @Bergi Thanks! Any idea how to invert the relationship then? I want to make sure there is 1-to-1 correspondence between variable and scalar type. E.g. `NumVariable` should push and provide access to `Num`s, a `DisVariable` (discrete) variable should push and provide access to `Dis`, etc...

Comment: Then you should use an interface where you pass `Num` as a generic parameter (like `Variable<Num>`), not `VariableLike<number>`, as there might be other classes that implement `VariableLike<number>`. Also for `push` I don't see a reason to restrict it to only `Num`s, it would actually work fine with any `ScalarLike<number>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions are *contravariant* in their parameters (see [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) ), so it's not safe for them to accept only narrower types as arguments.  When [the `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strictFunctionTypes) is enabled, this is enforced for non-method function types (a function type is `{a: ()=>void}`, while a method type is `{a(): void}`).

---

For some reason the demonstrations about this [tend to involve animals](https://web.archive.org/web/20220823104433/https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance), so I might as well do the same thing:

If I want a `Pet`, I'd be happy if you gave me a `Goldfish`.

```
interface Pet { name: string; }
interface Goldfish extends Pet { swim(): void; }
declare const goldfish: Goldfish;
const pet: Pet = goldfish; // okay
```

But if I want a *veterinarian* (`(pet: Pet) => void`), I'd be *unhappy* if you directed me to some sort of goldfish-only specialist (`(gf: Goldfish) => void`):

```
type Veterinarian = (pet: Pet) => void;
type GoldfishDoctor = (goldfish: Goldfish) => void;
declare const gfdoc: GoldfishDoctor
let vet: Veterinarian = gfdoc; // error!
// Property 'swim' is missing in type 'Pet' but required in type 'Goldfish'.
```

Maybe that wouldn't bother me if I happened to have a goldfish, but I didn't ask for a goldfish doctor, I asked for a veterinarian.  Certainly Doctor Goldfish shouldn't be advertising herself as a veterinarian.  When you bring your cat to her and she can't help you, it isn't much comfort for her to say "but a `Goldfish` is a `Pet`".

Functions can't safely narrow their argument types.  They can only safely *widen* them.  For example, a business that was accepted either sick animals or dirty laundry would be a valid veterinarian:

```
interface Laundry { material: string; }
type ComboVetAndDryCleaners = (arg: Pet | Laundry) => void;
declare const comboDoc: ComboVetAndDryCleaners
vet = comboDoc; // okay
```

So that's why you have the problem.  You can't say you accept all `ScalarLike<number>` and then only accept `Num`.

---

Of course, people write unsafe code like this all the time without problems, because often nobody thinks to pass "the wrong" narrower thing in.  So when you are using *method syntax* instead of *function syntax*, even `--strictFunctionTypes` doesn't enforce it.  Instead, method parameters are checked *bivariantly*, meaning they accept safe widening but also unsafe narrowing.  So the most expedient "fix" here is to change `VariableLike`'s `push` to be a method and not a function-valued property:

```
type VariableLike<T> = {
  ith: (index: () => number) => ScalarLike<T>;
  push(scalar: ScalarLike<T>): number;
};
```

That resolves your errors.  It's still unsafe, but possibly this won't matter in practice.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgAoTMg3skcC2EAXMgM5hSgDmA3MgL4BQoksiKA4gPYA2AJjGCkAFsggAPSCD6k0GbGQDuwfAAoAlCQBuXYHzpM+EBDzhQUCLiHLIqvAUOElu-QSJqNL1zAAcMJdEwAXlt7N2E6AHpI5C4AazgAT0ZGMES-ZAA1DGhQM2A4EGQQ1T8wAIx1YoA+ZB09DzSMlwcRABEuBDAuKGLkVTtXR2cwxyqg2vr9RiMTMwsrGyoYPk6RofbO7qhGHnktfyycyjxKQr7l1YQomOgoHoBCRmi0e78oNOQAclJlfC-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-SOUJ0G5tlWXOZkm6KN5ekfX+QORXNC2iCUKlpQ5uY4OmLwAKJQPcUDvm1XzrXxm3fdUAJAiCpbgjZyAwLwPBcMoIBUP+bzQGAm6yDA9z4DiZP2V82gGbGf7mXwf6xVo8VJZe6bmGACJQJCCNE0khLzYtKllSjl6MfQQA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed & really nicely written up explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The whole TS error would be:

```
Property 'push' in type 'NumVariable' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'VariableLike<number>'.
  Type '(num: Num) => number' is not assignable to type '(scalar: ScalarLike<number>) => number'.
    Types of parameters 'num' and 'scalar' are incompatible.
      Type 'ScalarLike<number>' is missing the following properties from type 'Num': valueLike, add, divideBy(2416)
```

That's because you are not satisfying the `push` signature like described in the `VariableLike` implementation.

You can *pass* a narrow type to `push` though:

```
class NumVariable implements VariableLike<number> {
  constructor(private array: number[]) {}
  ith = (index: () => number) => new Num(new View(this.array, index));
  push = (num: ScalarLike<number>) => {
    return this.array.push(num.value());
  };
}

const n = new NumVariable([]);

n.push(new Num(new Value(1)));
```

Because `Num` implements `ScalarLike`.